# Split lines of current paragraph in Emacs

Tags: emacs, split, lisp

I want to add a function (para2lines) to Emacs by which I can split the current paragraph into its sentences and print them line by line in a separate buffer. Following is code in Racket/Scheme:

```
(define (p2l paraString)
  (define lst (string-split paraString ". "))
  (for ((i lst))
    (displayln i)))
```

Testing:

```
(p2l "This is a test. For checking only. Only three lines.")
```

Output:

```tex
This is a test.
For checking only.
Only three lines.
```

In Emacs Lisp, I could manage following code:

```lisp
(defun pl (ss)
  (interactive)
  (let ((lst (split-string (ss))))
    (while lst
      (print (pop lst)))))
```

But I do not know how to get the text from the paragraph with current position. How can I correct this function?

Edit: basically, I want to read it as separate lines but want to save it as paragraph.

Comment: What do you mean "save it is a paragraph"?

Comment: Means let it be as a paragraph in the original document. So, splitting para into lines is for reading purposes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just run Emacs commands or write a macro to convert a paragraph to single-sentence lines, but maybe you are really just wanting to read wrapped paragraphs as lines, thus the need to have an Emacs command.

Here's something that will grab the current paragraph, insert a new buffer `*Lines*`, and then convert sentences to lines.

```
(defun para-lines ()
  "Split sentences of paragraph to lines in new buffer."
  (interactive)
  ;; Move the paragraph to a new buffer.
  (let ((b (generate-new-buffer "*Lines*")))
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer b
      (let ((beg (save-excursion (forward-paragraph -1) (point)))
            (end (save-excursion (forward-paragraph +1) (point))))
        (princ (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))))
    ;; Switch to new buffer
    (with-current-buffer b
      ;; Since the name starts with "*", shut off Help Mode
      (fundamental-mode)
      ;; Make sure buffer is writable
      (setq buffer-read-only nil)
      ;; From the start of the buffer
      (goto-char (point-min))
      ;; While not at the end of the buffer
      (while (< (point) (point-max))
        (forward-sentence 1)
        ;; Delete spaces between sentences before making new new line
        (delete-horizontal-space)
        ;; Don't add a new line, if already at the end of the line
        (unless (= (line-end-position) (point))
            (newline))))))
```

To avoid using `forward-sentence`, and just use a regular expression, use `re-search-forward`.   For instance, to match semi-colons as well as periods.

```
(defun para-lines ()
  "Split sentences of paragraph to lines in new buffer."
  (interactive)
  ;; Move the paragraph to a new buffer.
  (let ((b (generate-new-buffer "*Lines*")))
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer b
      (let ((beg (save-excursion (forward-paragraph -1) (point)))
            (end (save-excursion (forward-paragraph +1) (point))))
        (princ (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))))
    ;; Switch to new buffer
    (with-current-buffer b
      ;; Since the name starts with "*", shut off Help Mode
      (fundamental-mode)
      ;; Make sure buffer is writable
      (setq buffer-read-only nil)
      ;; From the start of the buffer
      (goto-char (point-min))
      ;; While not at the end of the buffer
      (while (< (point) (point-max))
        (re-search-forward "[.;]\\s-+" nil t)
        ;; Delete spaces between sentences before making new new line
        (delete-horizontal-space)
        ;; Don't add a new line, if already at the end of the line
        (unless (= (line-end-position) (point))
            (newline))))))
```

Comment: Yes, I want to read it as separate lines but want to save it as paragraph.

Comment: Your code is not working. Did you try it yourself? It opens a new buffer but does not separate the lines. Code by @gilez is working (although in the same buffer). Possibly one needs to check for strings ". "  and replace them with "\n" .

Comment: Looks like your sentences end in a single space.  Did you `M-x customize-variable RET sentence-end-double-space RET nil RET` ?

Comment: How can I do that from init.el file so that it is there at startup?

Comment: It is not working despite M-x customize-variable RET sentence-end-double-space RET nil RET.

Comment: The new buffer created by your function is read-only. Can that be writable? I can then apply function by @gilez to the paragraph transferred by your function in the new buffer!

Comment: It will be useful if you can insert comments in code explaining what is being done.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that might help you on your way. It will do your conversion to the current paragraph (i.e. where the cursor is positioned), rather than to a new buffer. You could modify this to pass a string to your function if that's what you require.

```el
(defun p2l ()
  "Format current paragraph into single lines."
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (forward-paragraph)
    (let ((foo (point)))
      (backward-paragraph)
      (replace-regexp "\n" " " nil (1+ (point)) foo)
      (backward-paragraph)
      (replace-regexp "\\. ?" ".\n" nil (point) foo))))
```

Comment: Also look into `forward-sentence`, which will handle all sorts of corner cases, and can be tuned with some variables to get the behavior you want.

Comment: How can the output be in a new buffer?

Comment: How can I add another regex (say "; ?") also to be replaced with ";\n"

Comment: To add another regex, use the pattern above (`backward-paragraph` and `replace-regexp`). Or you could get clever with the existing regex, with two different match options separated by `|` ... something like `(\\.|;) ?` Just be wary of the old: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

Comment: It will be useful if you can insert comments in code explaining what is being done.

Comment: @rnso while I agree comments in code are good, that example is so trivial, if you're having trouble understanding what things like `backward-paragraph` and `replace -regexp` do, then you have a lot to learn. Perhaps try `^h f` and a function name to read the docs on what a particular function does....